# Generated mongodb query for findAllOrderByFieldDesc in Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data

I'm trying to build simple auto generated query for my entity to sort by some number field in descending order as follows:

```
@Document(collection = "my_coll")
class MyEntity (

    @Id
    val id: ObjectId = ObjectId.get(),

    val someField: Number

)

...

interface MyEntityRepository : MongoRepository<MyEntity, String> {
//this is failing query I try to build
    fun findAllOrderbySomeFieldDesc(): List<MyEntity>
}
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllOrderbySomeFieldDesc found for type MyEntity
```

How can I achieve that?

#### UPDATE:

According to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-sorting#1-sorting-with-the-orderby-method-keyword) following function should work

```
fun findByOrderBySomeFieldDesc(): List<MyEntity>
//unfortunately it fails again for me with
//No property findAllOrderbySomeFieldDesc found for type MyEntity
```

My current working solution is to [use sorting with Sort parameter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-sorting#2-sorting-with-a-sort-parameter)

```
myEntityRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "someField"))
```

Question remains how to achieve the same with spring auto generated method?

Comment: try naming the method as findAllSortBySomeField

Comment: `Invalid parameter index! You seem to have declared too little query method parameters!`

Comment: What is the functionality of the method `findAllOrderbySomeFieldDesc()`?

Comment: So there should be a 'By' between All and Order. So either 
`public List<MyEntity> findAllByOrderBySomeFieldAsc();` or `public List<MyEntity> findAllBySortBySomeFieldAsc();` should work

Comment: Find all with sort by some_fld asc?

Comment: `there should be a 'By' between All and Order` that solved it thx @yevgeniy.batulin! 

@prasad_ sorry for mixing ASC and DESC in my description, I fixed that.

`findAllByOrderBySomeFieldAsc` works like a charm.

Comment: @yevgeniy.batulin I'm happy to accept it if you make it as an aswer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Officials Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject) query method subject keyword in your case should end with 'By' so the method name should be `findAllByOrderBySomeFieldDesc()`